# Deploying Flask with Celery App on Heroku using heroku.yml

Tags: docker, heroku, flask, redis, celery

I really don't know what I am doing. I am trying to deploy a Flask app with Celery on Heroku using a heroku.yml file and a Dockerfile.

This is my heroku.yml file:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
    worker: Dockerfile
run:
  web: gunicorn main:app
  worker: celery worker --app=main.celery
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Start with a base image
FROM python:3-onbuild
# Copy our application code
WORKDIR /Users/Owner/Lukas Projects/gift-apis
COPY requirements.txt .
# Fetch app specific dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . .
# Expose port
EXPOSE 5000
# start the app
CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app"]
```

I am not sure at this point if I even need the command at the end of the Dockerfile.

So in the end I am running **git push heroku master**

I get this error:

```
run.worker process type does not specify an image, such as:
remote: run:
remote:   worker:
remote:     command:
remote:       - celery worker --app=main.celery
remote:     image: <IMAGE NAME>
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

I am not sure what it needs in terms of an image... so I added the worker line under the docker section on the yml file. I really don't know what I am doing on the worker image. Help! Or, if you know a better way to deploy Flask with Celery on Heroku using Docker image, I am all ears. Also, if it matters I am using Redis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you need to supply a base image for the worker. (I'm surprised it's not complaining about the web service, but maybe it's just hitting the worker first and failing.)

You should specify images for each of your run entries:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
    worker: Dockerfile
run:
  web: 
    command:
      - gunicorn main:app
    image: web
  worker: 
    command:
      - celery worker --app=main.celery
    image: worker
```

You could also simplify your config by creating a single base image, since they're both identical and using that in both places.

Also, you may want to move your startup commands into scripts, as they'll be much easier to work with *and* you can use them during development when bringing these services up.

Regarding your question about the `CMD` entry, you can remove it since it looks like you're overriding it everywhere the image is used.

Comment: How can I do to have two workers?

Comment: @EduardoGomes I don't know. Regardless, you should open a dedicated question about that problem.